# Securing A Web Service .Net

Tags: .net, web-services

I am looking all over the internet and cannot seem to find a good example on how to pass credentials to a web service to secure it.

Can someone point me to a detailed sample how to add security to a web service?

It looks like everyone is using a WCF Model for this. Is ASMX getting phased out? If not I am looking to pass credentials to ASMX, otherwise see the WCF approach.
Any good tutorials on this subject you guys know of?

Comment: Please be more specific: ASMX, WCF, REST, some protocol you have just invented (in which case please describe it), ... When someone says *web service in .NET* this means noting to me: a contextless, technologyless stuff.

Comment: @Darin ASMX is what I am trying to find

Comment: then please retag your question with this information.

Comment: @Darin Actually it looks like everyone is using a WCF Model for this. Any good tutorials on this you know of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here:

- [Programming WCF Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731925.aspx) at MSDN
- [WCF Security Guidance](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/) by Microsoft Patterns & Practices

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using WCF as a platform for your web service (not legacy asmx services).

There are different ways to secure the service. It depends on what kind of credentials you have.

[Programming WCF Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731925.aspx)

If you have custom username/password security, you might want to look at `TransportWithMessageCredential` option.